# What anti-DDoS solutions for Windows are there?

Tags: windows, attack-prevention, denial-of-service, ddos

I would love to know, If there is a way to mitigate DDos/Dos attacks on Windows. In Linux we can Mitigate using the almighty `iptables`, but I wonder if there an equivalent for Windows.

Comment: The Windows Firewall Almighty, of course

Comment: @Stephane Need some references, I asked already If we can do this with Netsh Firewall, but no answer

Comment: Mitigating DDoS? Not really, but for mitigating DoS - absolutely. Do it the same way as with iptables.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you already know IPTables, which is software mitigation, you could do the same thing in Windows by simply scanning the DNS requests and block IPs in the firewall.

It's important to understand that this won't help if your hardware fails under the load.
You might get a better answer at ServerFault.

Comment: Yes I know blocking requests will work, but actually how.. Thats what I am asking